# Custom data attribute not working with Material UI 5 using textfield select prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, custom-attribute

Previously I was using Material UI v4 using the Textfield select prop and was able to retrieve my custom data attribute via event.currentTarget.dataset. However, now I'm using Material UI v5 it logs out null in my onchange handler.

Anyone else experienced this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        const handleChange = (e) => {
        /** ID FROM INPUT FIELD */
        console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset); ---> logs out null

        <Grid item>
         <TextField
           select
           name='rpe'
           inputProps={{
            'data-setid': `${localSetId.current}`,
            'data-exerciseid': `${localExerciseId.current}`
           }}
           style={isMatched ? { width: 69 } : { minWidth: 200 }}
           variant='outlined'
           size={isMatched ? 'small' : 'medium'}
           label='rpe'
           onChange={handleChange}
           defaultValue=''
         >
          {rpeList.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
       </TextField>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the MUI **select** functionality supports data-attributes, but an alternative solution is to pass an object as a second argument for the **handleChange** function

```js
const handleChange = (e, dataset) => {
        /** ID FROM INPUT FIELD */
        console.log(e, dataset); // now it will print both event and the new data object
}
        <Grid item>
         <TextField
           select
           name='rpe'
           style={isMatched ? { width: 69 } : { minWidth: 200 }}
           variant='outlined'
           size={isMatched ? 'small' : 'medium'}
           label='rpe'
           onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, {setId:1, exerciseId: 2})}
           defaultValue=''
         >
          {rpeList.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
       </TextField>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried the Select component it doesn't work as well. Im not trying to get the input value. I've set an id attribute on the dom and i want to retrieve that id to do some logic when the on change handler fires

Comment: aha i understood you wrong, i edited my solution above , you can try it now

Comment: As mentioned in v4 my code works like a charm and i got what i wanted to achieve.  For example when my set component renders i get the data attributes like so

Comment: yeah , i know but i think they changed the structure in v5

Comment: Damn that sucks! I realised on a normal Textfield data attribute does work but not on the Select component. Maybe its a bug or something. Your solution helped me. Thanks Mido